# Overcoming Cross-Domain issues

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Are there any ways to overcome the cross domain issues that occur when attempting to retrieve data client-side from another web server in violation of the Same Origin policy?

Comment: Can you be more precise? It's unreasonable to expect people to put more effort into an answer than you put into the question. Wait; I already have....

Comment: More information => better answers.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

Comment: Detailed example in using JSONP to do this: http://www.shanison.com/2012/05/11/cross-domain-ajax-request/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of referencing a third party domain directly from the client, call up to your hosting domain and have the server retrieve whatever you're getting from the third party domain.

Comment: ...Or simply modify your web application so that it retrieves the data server-side.

Comment: One scenario I had to work with didn't have that latitude.  In fact, it also didn't have the latitude to do what I described.  The senior dev (who was also the org's "security expert") suggested the "fix" of telling clients to turn off the cross-domain warning in IE.  Management buy-in for the cost of the "fix" shipped it.  I don't work there anymore.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Greg D, it is easy enough to make an AJAX call to a script on your domain that  uses curl to fetch a resource from another domain. Just remember that you will most likely want to cache the fetched file on your server so you don't have to go get it every single time a page is viewed.