# cross-domain $.ajax setRequestHeader

Tags: php, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overcoming Cross-Domain issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461768/overcoming-cross-domain-issues)

Is it possible to make a cross-domain $.ajax setRequestHeader ?

I´m trying to do this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://remote_url_here',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'TRUEREST username=xxxx&password=yyyy');
    },
    success: function() { alert('Sucess')},
    error: function() { alert('Error'); },
});
```

And in my "remote_url" im doing a `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` but its allways empty. I also tried looking in firebug but no headers are set, same thing if type:POST.
Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cross-site scripting, not allowed.

Comment: Both the server and the script have to set origin policies, or use the web server to make the cross domain request.

Comment: There are so many questions on the site about this topic, please search `cross-domain ajax` from the search bar.

Answer (score 10):

If you control http://remote_url_here you can via the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

or

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://permitted_domain.com');
```

Comment: Thanks, will look on that. Maybe it solves my problem :)

Comment: But, isnt it just for Firefox ? Since im developing a mobile app it wont work for me...

Comment: I've tried this under IE and Safari so it's not Firefox specific, your mobile browser milage may vary however. At worst, make a PHP script to act as a Proxy on the website you're creating the request from.

Comment: So, i tried the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); on my server app, and while using FF, it showed up in firebug. Unfortunatly, my authentication header still wasnt passed, using the code i provided on my question... maybe im missing something more ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a cross-domain ajax request due to javascript's [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), unless you use JSONP (which isn't useful in your case, I think).

Hope this helps. Cheers

**UPDATE** Now you can with the `crossDomain: true` option.

Comment: Hi, i knew cross-domain would be tricky and since im developing a mobile app its really needed. Im using a basic authentication on my server, and can get results with JSONP as u suggested. Unfortunatly it cant pass the header so im still stuck :(

Comment: Yes you can! see the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

add `crossDomain:true` to your `$.ajax()` params

Comment: Sorry, but that just didnt work :(